# Calling a method async does not work anymore after refactoring

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, future, juce

In order to separate my GUI from the logic (which fetches data from a REST service), I refactored some logic into a controller.

Now, only part of the logic seems to work.

The GUI component looks like this after refactoring (I am using the JUCE framework)

```
#pragma once
#include "../../JuceLibraryCode/JuceHeader.h"
#include "../../GUI.Controller/includes/ProjectEntryListController.h"
#include "ProjectEntryListComponent.h"
#include "LocalProjectEntryComponent.h"

class ProjectBrowserTabComponent : public TabbedComponent
{
public:
    ProjectBrowserTabComponent();
    ~ProjectBrowserTabComponent();

private:
    ProjectEntryListComponent m_remote_proj;
    ProjectEntryListComponent m_local_proj;
    ProjectEntryListController *pelccont = new ProjectEntryListController(&m_remote_proj);
    ProjectEntryListController *pelccont2 = new ProjectEntryListController(&m_local_proj);
};
```

The GUI controller looks like this:

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE
#include "../includes/ProjectEntryListController.h"

template<typename R>
bool isReady(std::future<R> const& f)
{
    Logger::writeToLog("check future");
    return f.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(-1)) == std::future_status::ready;
}

ProjectEntryListController::ProjectEntryListController(ProjectEntryListComponent *comp) {
    m_comp = comp;
    requestProjects();
}

void ProjectEntryListController::requestProjects()
{
    Logger::writeToLog("requesting projects");
    projectsFuture = std::async(std::launch::async, &ProjectsController::getProjects, &pc);
    Logger::writeToLog("requested projects");
}

void ProjectEntryListController::backgroundCheckFuture()
{
    timer = new boost::asio::deadline_timer(io_service, boost::posix_time::seconds(interval_secs));
    timer->async_wait(boost::bind(&ProjectEntryListController::fetchData, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, timer));
    ioSvcFuture = std::async(std::launch::async, static_cast<size_t(boost::asio::io_service::*)()>(&boost::asio::io_service::run), &io_service);
}

void ProjectEntryListController::initData() {
    requestProjects();
    backgroundCheckFuture();
}

void ProjectEntryListController::fetchData(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/,
    boost::asio::deadline_timer* tmr) {
    if (isReady(projectsFuture)) {
        projects = projectsFuture.get();
        for (auto project : projects)
        {
            ProjectEntryComponent *pec = new ProjectEntryComponent(std::to_string(project.getId()), "222");
            m_comp->addListEntry(pec);
            m_comp->repaint();
        }
        Logger::writeToLog("got projs");
    }
    else {
        tmr->expires_at(tmr->expires_at() + boost::posix_time::seconds(interval_secs));
        tmr->async_wait(boost::bind(&ProjectEntryListController::fetchData, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, tmr));
    }
}
```

The `requestProjects` method's log messages are appearing in my console, but not the log message of the `getProjects` method I am calling asynchronously:

```
std::vector<Project> ProjectsController::getProjects() {
    std::vector<Project> result;
    if(serviceClient != nullptr) {
        try
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds());
            std::cout << "controller requested projs\n";
            result = serviceClient->getAvailableProjects();
        }
        catch (const std::exception&)
        {

        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

However, when I debug into the code, the debugger (using VS 2015) also is able to step to the log message.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved this now.

1.) I was calling the wrong method `requestProjects` instead of `initData`

2.) I couldn't see the result because the implementation of `ProjectEntryComponent::ProjectEntryComponent(std::string name, std::string version)` was missing